# Get unique identifier of a mouse

Tags: mouse, hardware, device, wmic

When I check the hardware ID of my mouse in the device manager, it outputs `HID\VID_15D9&PID_0A4C&REV_0100`. The same ID is given for a different mouse of the same brand on another PC.

However, I want to have a unique identifier for each mouse, because I'm doing an inventory of laboratory equipment, and I have to audit hardware components of the lab.

I've used VBS and made use of WMIC commands. So far, I've tried this code to get the device ID of the mouse:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PointingDevice") 
Wscript.Echo "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID
```

How can I get a unique ID for each device?

Comment: What programming language are you using? [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I used vbs and made use of WMIC commands. SO far, I've tried this code to get the device ID of the mouse 
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PointingDevice")

 Wscript.Echo "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID

Comment: Please **do not duplicate** questions: [How to get unique id of a mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28273913/3439404)